# How to get database dependency/relationship among tables

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone give me an idea about database flow diagram in my SqlServer Server Management Studio? I have a database (ERBIA) in my server; I want to know about the database relationship among different tables.

Comment: @Mitch: fixed the yelling problem

Comment: Off Topic. While SQL Server has limited support for that in the end this is a tool recommendation - which is explicitly not welcome here. Check out Visio ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply click on this:

[image: Image showing how to create SQL Dependency Graphs]

And then select the tables for which you wish to create diagrams (graphs)

Answer (score 0):

By database flow diagram I think you mean an Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD). There are a number of 3rd party tools that exist to create ERDs. ERWin, Visio, ER/Studio are some examples.

These tools can read the database schema information and create a diagram and draw relationship lines based on the Foreign Key constraints. You can edit the diagrams and depending on the tool update the database or generate a DDL script for the database changes.

SQL Server also includes a [database designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188251.aspx), but it should be noted there is no separation from a logical model and the physical model. This means if you draw a line from one table to another indicating a relationship a FK will actually be created when you save the diagram. For some scenarios this would be a problem.